# Unexpected Results Splicing on Spreaded Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This code is for a simple todo app built in react. Today I was trying to refactor my option 1 code into something like option 2 and was surprised to see that it broke my removeTask functionality. During troubleshooting I also tried option 3, which had the same results. I'm struggling to figure out why; to me option 2 and 3 look pretty much the same as option 1, just cleaner. When implementing option 2 or 3 I get no errors, yet clicking removeTask now deletes all the previous tasks. What is the difference between these three?

The problem code:

```
//Option 1 (working)
removeTask = (event, index) => { 
  event.stopPropagation();
  const removedTaskArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];

  removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1);                                      
  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });         
};


//Option 2 (broken)
removeTask = (event, index) => {                          
  event.stopPropagation();                                 
  const removedTaskArray = [...this.state.tasksarray].splice(index, 1);     

  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });    
};


//Option 3 (broken)
removeTask = (event, index) => {                          
  event.stopPropagation();                                 
  const copyOfTasksArray = [...this.state.tasksarray]    
  const removedTaskArray = copyOfTasksArray.splice(index, 1);     

  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });    
};
```

Full (working) code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

/* InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method. */
const InputTaskForm = ({ formValidation }) => { 
    return (                                      
      <form name="charlie" onSubmit={formValidation}>
        <input name="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Task..." /> 
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
}

const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
  return (
    <div id="orderedList">
      <ol>
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <li onClick={() => strikeTask(index)} key={index} >
            {task.strike ? <strike>{task.title}</strike> : task.title}
            <button id="removeButton" onClick={event => removeTask(event, index)} >Remove</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userinput: '',
    tasksarray: [],                               
  }


/* ============================================== #FUNCTIONS ============================================== 
=========================================================================================================== */
formValidation = event => {                                 // event prop passed from InputTaskForm component
  event.preventDefault();                                   // prevent form from auto-refreshing on submit
  const userInput = event.target.userinput.value            // userInput stored
  const userInputIsBlank = userInput.trim().length < 1      // trim (remove) prefixed and affixed spaces, then check length

  userInputIsBlank 
    ? alert(`Error: invalid submission`) 
    : this.storeTask(userInput);
};


storeTask = userInput => {                                  // userInput passed from formValidation function
    this.setState({
      userinput: userInput,
      tasksarray: [...this.state.tasksarray, { title: userInput, strike: false } ] //create a copy of tasks array then add a new object into the array filled out with user input
    });
    document.forms["charlie"].reset();
};


//Option 1 (working)
removeTask = (event, index) => { 
  event.stopPropagation();
  const removedTaskArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];

  removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1);                                      
  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });         
};


strikeTask = index => {                                    // index prop passed from DisplayTasks component
  const { tasksarray } = this.state
  const selected = tasksarray[index];

  this.setState({                                           
    tasksarray: [                                           // change tasksarray state to: [prior slice, change, after slice]
      ...tasksarray.slice(0, index),                        // slice off (copies) of array elements prior to index element
      Object.assign(selected, {strike: !selected.strike}),  // invert the selected line's strike value
      ...tasksarray.slice(index + 1)                        // slice off (copies) of array elements after index element
    ]
  });
};


componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.tasksarray);                       // debugging :) 
};


/* =============================================== #RENDER ================================================ 
=========================================================================================================== */
  render() { 
    const { tasksarray } = this.state
    const { formValidation, storeTask, removeTask, strikeTask } = this

    return (
      <div>
        <InputTaskForm 
          task={storeTask}
          formValidation={formValidation} />


        <DisplayTasks 
          tasks={tasksarray} 
          removeTask={removeTask} 
          strikeTask={strikeTask} />
      </div>
      );
    };
};


/* ================================================ #EXPORT =============================================== 
=========================================================================================================== */
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Return value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) of splice is

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

So in your 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> method you're placing deleted element arrays

so you can simply change your code to

```
removeTask = (event, index) => {                          
  event.stopPropagation();                                 
  const removedTaskArray = [...this.state.tasksarray]
  removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1);     
  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });    
};
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhh.....the line I was comprehending incorrectly in my code was removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1); For some reason I was reading/thinking of it as .splice(index, 1) still being attached to removedTasksArray on the next line. But in actuality its just making the splice modification on that specific line.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to understanding what does [Array##splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) it actually returns an array containing the deleted items. Here is a small example:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(3, 1); // same as a = [4]
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const c = b.splice(3, 1); // same as b = [1, 2, 3, 5] and c = [4]
```

Comment: I understand this. But why does splicing on the spreaded array directly not work, but storing the spreaded array in a variable first then splicing the variable does? In both cases you're splicing the same thing? In the second case it's just stored in a variable first. This is what I see when looking at option 1 vs 2.

Comment: All in all « a » and « c » are the same. Now, you start with a full array of values that you store in « b » and once you call splice with the intention of deleting an item, the array that you previously stored in « b » will be mutated and what has been deleted would be stored in « c ».

Comment: Figured it out based on the other answer. So it wasn't that I was misunderstanding how splice modifies some code, but incorrectly comprehending the transitions from the splice line in option 1 and the setstate line. For some dumb reason I thought .splice(index, 1) was still attached to removedTaskArray e.g. I read the setState line as this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1) }) when in reality .splice only did work on the previous line.